# Авто преобразования базовых типов данных char int с#

Tags: c#, методы, типы-данных

Всем привет. Решил задачу с перегруженным статическим методом. Если изначально строго прописывать int или char в методе Main, то программа работает корректно (если мы вводим определенный тип данных).
Но как реализовать ввод через консоль чтобы можно было и char и int вводить?
(добавляю, сейчас реализация через ввод int в консоль=> перегруженный статический метод задействован на половину, можно поменять в Main на char, все будет также, но вводить в консоль придется символы. А чтобы программа работала и при вводе char и при int данных из консоли) Необходимо унифицированное решение вне зависимости от типов данных

```
using System;
    class T_5_8 
    {
        static void Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int size = (num2 - num1) + 1;
            int[] Arr = new int[size];
    
            for (int k = 1; k < Arr.Length; k++)
            {
                Arr[0] = num1;
                Arr[k] = num1 + k;
            }
            foreach (int s in Arr)
            {
                Console.Write("|" + s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("|");
        }
        static void Add(char symb1, char symb2)
        {
            int size = (char)(symb2 - symb1) + 1;
            char[] Arr = new char[size];
            for (int k = 1; k < Arr.Length; k++)
            {
                Arr[0] = symb1;
                Arr[k] = (char)(symb1 + k);
            }
            foreach (char s in Arr)
            {
                Console.Write("|" + s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("|");
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите n1");
            int n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите n2");
            int n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Add(n1, n2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Но как реализовать ввод через консоль чтобы можно было и char и int вводить?` Опишите подробнее, какое поведение вы ожидаете. В чем будет разница между вводом int и char?

Comment: `Необходимо унифицированное решение вне зависимости от типов данных` как именно вы планируете отличить число `3` от символа `'3'` при вводе из консоли? Чем должен отличаться ввод пользователя в обоих случаях?

Comment: @aepot на ввод будет подаваться либо A F, либо 1 5

Comment: То есть ввод одной цифры должен распознаваться как число, а не как символ, верно?

Comment: @aepot Да, все верно

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забрать один или первый символ из консольного ввода можно например так

```
char c1 = Console.ReadLine()[0];
```

Либо так

```cs
char c1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
Console.WriteLine();
```

С точки зрения надежности логики, второй способ лучше.

> Необходимо унифицированное решение вне зависимости от типов данных

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(input, out int number))
{
    // int number - введено число
}
else if (input.Length > 0)
{
    char c = input[0];
    // char c - введен символ
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
```